# How do I remove a preferred application

Tags: xubuntu

I basically did a stupid as I was having issues with getting mailto links working in chrome...
So what I did was set google-chrome as a preferred application for handling mail, which backfired and exploded in my face...

Now I seem to be stuck with my mistake as I can't seem to undo my changes:
[image]
^ what I want is the blank box as I don't have anything installed to manage mail...
I have a chrome extension that does that for me.

Comment: no I'm not asking about how to fix google chrome, just clearing that up if anyone should get the idea to comment about it...
I already have that open here:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/c4e6j66-v0Y;context-place=forum/chrome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Preferred Applications app creates desktop launchers in `~/.local/share/xfce4/helpers` for each associate category that has an assigned application.

Removing those launchers unassigns the applications for those categories, thus clearing the associated app.

Comment: Just to note, I want to give credit to @Legolas, as he posted a link in a removed post to https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Default_applications#XDG_standard which helped me track down the location the launchers were created in.

Comment: hmm. I only have chromium-browser.desktop there no matter what I change in Preferred Applications. (Xubuntu 18.04)

Answer (score 0):

You can set your default mail app from the command line using:

`sudo update-alternatives --config mail`

Once prompted, enter the number of the program you wish to handle mail and hit enter.

Comment: That returns `update-alternatives: error: no alternatives for mail`, like I said in the question, I have nothing installed, however this is a nice trick for those who do have stuff installed and don't like GUIs, but the Preferred Applications app in the question would work there as well.

Comment: To add, another reason this wouldn't work is because of the cause, since I'm using chrome on Xubuntu (evident via the xfce preferred applications app), chrome defaults to the app's location from some config somewhere I don't want to get into, where `update-alternatives` I believe operates on an apt backend. If I uninstalled the xfce4 preferred applications app, this would likely work then.